# Authentication with socket-io and jwt

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, jwt

When a user enters my application, I give him a `token`. a part of my project i'm using chat application and i want to give `the token` to the user and check it on server. everything works fine, but if `the token` changes or is not received on the server, i can't handle the error and send it to ui. when i have the error `next()` does not work.

***server:***

app.js:

```
  io.use((socket, next) => {
    if (socket.handshake.headers.authorization) {
      try {
        const token = socket.handshake.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
        tkn({ token, from: "socket-io" }, next);
      } catch (error) {
        next(new Error("Authentication failed"));
      }
    } else {
      next(new Error("Authentication failed"));
    }
  });

  io.on("connection", socket => {
    console.log(socket);
    require("./controllers/socket-io/socket-io-controller")(socket, io);
  });
```

tkn.js:

```
module.exports.tkn = ({ token, from, req }, next) => {
  if (!token) {
    throw new Error("authentication failed");
  }

  const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, "iuSiosIUSG275678SJDFGJAG");

  if (from === "rest") {
    req.userId = decodedToken.userId;
  }

  return next();
};
```

socket-io-controller.js:

```
const socketHandler = (socket, io) => {
  socket.on("chat", data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
};

module.exports = socketHandler;
```

***client:***

```
  useEffect(() => {
    io = socketIo("http://localhost:5000", {
      extraHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer ${authContext.token}` }
    });
  }, []);
```

submit handler:

```
  const sendMessage = (e, userId, value, callback) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (io) {
      io.emit("chat", value);
    }

    callback && callback();
  };
```

Comment: Is your `jwt` getting expired when you are expecting the `error` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2763906/bhaskeryadav No, just when the token is wrong i want to send the error to client. do you know how can i do that?